# Gradle dependson vs. defaultTasks in multi-project

Tags: gradle

A small question about how Gradle (version 3.3) resolves task dependencies in a multi-project setting (with java subprojects). I'm quite new to gradle so maybe it's a stupid question...

I want to achieve a task being executed before compilation and one after compilation.

Using defaultTasks it works as expected. But when defining a task with dependsOn it doesn't.

My root `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
defaultTasks 'a', 'classes', 'b'

task a {
    doLast {
        println 'before compile'
    }
}

task b {
    doLast {
        println 'after compile'
    }
}

task doIt(dependsOn: [a, 'classes', b]) {
    doLast {
        println('done!')
    }
}

allprojects {
    group = 'foo'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.atlassian.com/3rdparty/'
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    ext {
        springVersion = '4.3.5.RELEASE'
    }
    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    }
}
```

When I execute `gradle` the default tasks are executed as expected: I get "before compile", then all subprojects are compiled, then "after compile".

When I execute `gradle doIt` I get the following error message

```
Task with path 'classes' not found in root project 'teambits-core'.
```

Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your build.gradle as it is, just running 'gradle' gives the same error on my 3.3 installation.

There are 2 issues you're facing here.

**1. Multiproject subprojects vs allprojects**

The first issue is that the defaultTasks is defined in the main build.gradle but your java plugin is only included in subprojects.

In a multi-project build, the 'master' project is not part of the subprojects section (only allprojects affects the master project), but your 'defaultTasks' is defined at the top level, so running 'gradle' will invoke the defaultTasks in the master project and fail on the classes task because it doesn't load the java plugin.

To fix this, move the 'apply plugin' line to allprojects (but only for this illustration, normally you don't want the java plugin loaded in master as it's generally about setting up the sub-projects).

**2. defaultTasks vs dependsOn**

The second issue is (assuming you move the apply plugin) then you will hit the real difference between defaultTasks and dependsOn.

The defaultTasks runs the tasks in the order you specify:

```
$ gradle
:a
before compile
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:b
after compile

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.765 secs
```

But running doIt with the list order will cause gradle to run them in alphabetical order (as there are no dependencies between them and in such scenarios it will run them alphabetically).

```
$ gradle doit
:a
before compile
:b
after compile
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:doIt
done!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.733 secs
```

**Fix Dependency Order with mustRunAfter**

In this case, you can fix it by adding the following to doIt:

```
task doIt(dependsOn: [a, 'classes', b]) {
    b.mustRunAfter(':classes')
    doLast {
        println('done!')
    }
}
```

which will force the b task to be done later.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Mark! Especially the .mustRunAfter was very helpful.

Comment: @Axel - glad i could help. I actually found your question because I had a similar problem, and in solving my problem, it solved yours too.

Comment: That's one of these win-win situations :-)